# Get value from child Array with a given ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have the following Array and I'm trying to print the child array value using `.find` by providing an ID

```
connections = [
    {
      group: 'a',
      items: [
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'Andre'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'David'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      group: 'b',
      items: [
        {
          id: '3',
          name: 'Brandon'
        }
      ]
    },
]
```

I have tried the following in my Angular app,

```
getUser(id) {
    this.activeItem = this.connections.items.find(data => data.id === id);
    console.log(this.activeItem);
}
```

I'm providing the correct ID but I'm getting an error saying,

> error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type....

Thank you.

Comment: Because it doesn't. `this.connections[0].items` does exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `some`  methods. This approach will filter array and your array will contain only desired items:

```js
let connections = [
    {
      group: 'a',
      items: [
        {
          id: '1', name: 'Andre'
        },
        {
          id: '2', name: 'David'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      group: 'b',
      items: [
        {
          id: '3', name: 'Brandon'
        }
      ]
    },
]

let id = 3;
// ONE WAY
const result = connections.filter(f=> f.items.some(s=> s.id == id))
                          .flatMap(fm => fm.items);
console.log(`result: `, result);

// OR ANOTHER WAY:
const resultWithGroup = connections.filter(f=> f.items.some(s=> s.id == id));
const resultItem = Object.assign({}, ...resultWithGroup).items.find(f => f.id == id);
console.log(`resultItem: `, resultItem);
console.log(`resultItem as an array: `, [resultItem]);
```

In addition, it is possible to use [flatMap method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). By using this approach you are getting all items with desired `id` and then find the first element with `id == 3`:

```js
let connections = [
    {
      group: 'a',
      items: [
        {
          id: '1', name: 'Andre'
        },
        {
          id: '2', name: 'David'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      group: 'b',
      items: [
        {
          id: '3', name: 'Brandon'
        }
      ]
    },
]

const result = connections.flatMap(f => f.items).find(f => f.id == id);
console.log(`result as array`, [result]);
```

Comment: Thank you, learned about 'some'. Can you also show how to assign the output to an array as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **flatMap**

Try like this:

```
getUser(id) {
  this.activeItem = this.connections.flatMap(x => x.items).find(data => data.id === id);
  console.log(this.activeItem);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatmap-data?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

As i can see from the Json object, the `items` arrays are grouped inside their parent objects. So first you would have to flatten the grouped array:

```
let items = []
connections.forEach(obj => obj.items.forEach( item => items.push(item)))
```

Now the `items` array would only be item objects so it will be easier to do a find:

```
items.find(item => item.id == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an array without specifying the element of the array

```
-----------------\/ here
this.connections[0].items.find(data => data.id === id);
```

Comment: Really worth an answer?

Comment: @mplungjan That is the root cause  of the error, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but worth an answer? I commented and flagged as typo-type

Comment: typo-TYPE! _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: fair enough, didn't know there was a flag specific for this type of question

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that you get this error: "error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type....".
Actually, 'connections' is an array and does not have any prperty 'items'.
'items' is an attribut of the elements contained in 'connections' array.

You can try something like:

```
getUser(id) {
    for (const element of this.connections) {
      this.activeItem = element.items.find(data => data.id === id);
      if (this.activeItem) {
          break;
      }
    }
    console.log(this.activeItem);
}
```

Once 'this.activeItem' is found we exit the loop with the 'break;' statement.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your "this.connections.items.find" is not working is that connections variable here represents an array of objects, you cannot directly access a key that is inside an objects contained in an array of objects.

Use this code instead:

```
this.activeItem = this.connections.filter(obj => obj.items.find(val => val.id == id));
console.log(this.activeItem.items);
```

Answer (score 0):

connections variable is an array and you are trying to access it as an object. PFB the below code it should be working fine for you.

```
    getUser(id) {
        this.activeItem = connections.find(function(element) {  return element.items.find(function(el){return el.id==id;}); });
        console.log(this.activeItem); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (You made mistake with `connections.items`)

```
getUser(id) {
    let activeItemIndex = -1;
    this.connections.forEach((c) => {
      activeItemIndex = c.items.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
      if (activeItemIndex > -1) {
        this.activeItem = c.items[activeItemIndex];
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify `index` of `connections`.

But this is the better solution, Because you have all the users in one place:

```
getUser(id) {
    users = connections.reduce((users, item)=>{
        users.push(...item.items);
        return users;
    }, []);
    this.activeItem = users.find(data => data.id === id);
    console.log(this.activeItem);
}
```

Comment: No explanation as to why OP had a problem. Just code without explanation - and not very understandable/elegant  code either. Try this: `connections.map(x => x.items).flat().find(data => data.id === "1")`

Comment: i have diffrent solution of you, Where is my code wrong?

Comment: Not wrong - just please add some explanation why OP's code did not work.

Comment: Because you had no explanation and your code is unnecessarily complex - I removed my vote